# Bug in UITableView ( deleteSections:withRowAnimation: )?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, animation

I have problems using this [UITableView method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteSections%3awithRowAnimation%3a):

```
- (void)deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

First the documentation says:

> animation:
>       YES to animate the deletion of sections, otherwise NO.

But the parameter animation is actually of type enum `UITableViewRowAnimation`, not `BOOL`!?

So how can I disable the animation? I've tried `NO` and `UITableViewRowAnimationNone`. Nothing works. The section deletion is always animated.

I know that I can use `[tableView reloadData]` instead. That would solve my issue. I'm just curious if that is a known problem and if it is possible to disable animation with this tableview method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the YES/NO in the doc whereas the parameter is of type UITableViewRowAnimation, I guess this is a rest from an old version of the API where the parameter was a BOOL before. Anyway, the documentation is indeed wrong.

Don't hesitate to send a feedback to Apple for this (using the "It's good but…" link at the bottom of the doc)

Answer (score 43):

It's kind of a hack but this gets rid of the insert animation:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertedIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: @samvermette thank you! thank you!  after an hour of getting frustrated, this was the answer I needed.

Comment: Oh no... It is sooo dirty. But works perfectly! Also as UIView methods are global I would recommend to use the following structure: 

`BOOL animationsWereEnabled = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertedIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:animationsWereEnabled]; `

Comment: Not sure if it matters since all UI updates are on the main thread, but in case other parts of your app are animating, I'm worried about globally turning animation on and off. You can wrap it in a block like this:
`[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
                    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertedIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                }];`

Answer (score 2):

Well, obviously the documentation is indeed buggy. The parameter you pass says how you animate the deletion. If you pass `UITableViewRowAnimationNone`, the update happens instantly without animation. However, when you have a section below the one you delete, it will move upwards in an animated way.

You should try to make use of the animations. This way a user can see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to embed the `deleteSections` call inside a `beginUpdates` block:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteSections:... withRowAnimation:... ];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html) seems to say this anyway. I haven't tested this with `UITableRowViewAnimationNone` though.