# UITableView reloadSection and reloadRowsAtIndexPaths causes weird animation

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, animation, lazy-loading

I am doing lazy loading for my UITableView so I am trying to reload individual rows as the images get updated. I am however running into a strange problem.

When I call,

```
    [self.bubbleTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

OR

```
    [self.bubbleTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[indexPath section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

When I specifically say No Animation it still animates and the animation is the Image taking up the entire cell and shrinking rapidly into the normal size. Also, if I change it to any other animation, it does the same animation no matter what setting.

If I comment either one of those out and just use reloadData it works fine, but I'd rather not do reloadData for performance reasons of reupdating cells that don't need updating.

Thanks!

Comment: same problem here. did you solve it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[Here was an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10868413/1558147)

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[self.bubbleTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[indexPath section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

It works for me.

UPD. Same with block by @Şafak-gezer

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    [self.bubbleTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[indexPath section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}];
```

**SWIFT**

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            self.bubbleTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

Below method worked for me: (for iOS 7 and better)

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[indexPath section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to only update the cell you are interested in.

Comment: I am not having issues with updating the ones I am interested in, but I am having trouble with updating the specific cells without this weird animation.

Comment: But if you get the cell (with cellForRowAtIndexPath), you can update the image in the cell. There will be no animation, because you don't call any reload* methods.

Comment: hmm.. I am updating the image in the cell, but the problem I am having is that the image doesn't update until I reloadData or if the cell goes off the screen and comes back on.

Comment: Seems like it's either an issue with the image or with the cell. Can you update text in the cell? If not, I wonder if you're updating the right cell. Note that cellForRowAtIndexPath returns nil if the cell is not currently visible.

Answer (score -3):

I found this happening to me on the iOS Simulator. After a few reloads it worked normally with no animation. Could be just a bug in the simulator.

Comment: it's happening on device, too