# Swapping out UITableView Sections. New section temporarily overlaps old

Tags: ios, uitableview

See this screencast: http://www.screencast.com/t/4KZu1ZBVDjs

Basically what is happening is that I'm flipping the view, and then as part of the animations of the flip, I'm swapping out sections to show different information.

For some reason when I delete sections and then insert others, or even if I just reload the sections (there happen to be the same number of them), in one direction it temporarily shows the old section below the new. So towards the end of the screencast, you can see the map is showing under the new cell (avatar and label), but then disappears.

It's not related to the flip animation itself. Even with that removed, same problem: http://www.screencast.com/t/iOcNTyDf

This one is a little perplexing.

Comment: It seems to still be animating despite: UITableViewRowAnimationNone. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the table seemed to be the better solution here, but this definitely appears to be a bug.

[Bug in UITableView ( deleteSections:withRowAnimation: )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431806/bug-in-uitableview-deletesectionswithrowanimation)