# Reload UITableView Header View without blink

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a problem with header view while reloading `UITableView`. Actually problem is with unexpected blinking the entire view just after reload. 
I want dynamically change the height of the view and this animation is definitely unwanted.
Is it possible to rid of this.

To reload section I use:

```
[self.table reloadSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: are you using [self.table reloadata]?

Comment: reloadSection, when I use `reloadData` I lose GestureRecognizer delegate from header section.

Comment: Try to remove header when you reload view and after set it back

Comment: what do you mean by `remove header`, maybe I haven't clarified it properly, the blinking occurs under Header section view when I reload section (to resize header view).

Comment: just for half second disappear header view and appear with new resized height.

Comment: i add my answer pls try

Comment: Issue has been solved by another thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10868413/1561414

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)swipeAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
CGFloat posY = [gesture translationInView:self.view].y;
self.dynamicHeight = posY;

NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];
[self reloadSection:indexSet];
}



- (void)reloadSection:(NSIndexSet *)indexSet
{

[self.tblContainer beginUpdates];
[self.tblContainer reloadSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tblContainer endUpdates];
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

UIViewController *vc = self.controllers[section];
if ([self.childViewControllers containsObject:vc]) {
} else {
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
return vc.view;
}



- (CGFloat)heightCell
{
return MIN_HEIGHT + dynamicHeight;
}



- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.controllers[section] heightCell];
}
```

Comment: The content of header view in section behaves strange when this view is resizing

Answer (score 0):

Hmm probably you should use this approach try to indicate when you start and end update of table view :

```
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.table reloadSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: ok, it's much better however under just refresh Header View I can notice the previous view. The out of date view is for a milliseconds visible under new header. It's not smooth enough transition, do you think it's possible to do it.